# Core dump while using an array with an index bigger than 50 in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am having some trouble while writing a simple program with pointers
and arrays. The goal is to insert a value of 128 into 512 indices of
an array using pointers. The problem is that if I use more than 50 indexes 
I am getting core dumped. Am I missing something or is it an environmental limitation?
Is malloc() needed or should I define the array somewhere else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#define MAX 512

int main(void){
    int  i, *p, a[MAX];
    i = 0;
    p = &a[0];
    for (i=0 ; i <= MAX; i++){
        *(p+i) = 128;
    }
    printf("First value  %d last value of pointer  %d\n", *p, *(p+(MAX-1)) );

}
```

Comment: `*(p+i)` with `i == MAX` is out-of-bounds for `a[MAX]`. Also, why not use `p[i]`? Much more pleasant to read.

Comment: You probably mean `<` rather than `<=` in your `for` loop

Comment: I thought that p is a pointer so the square brackets would not work.

Answer (score 5):

Change `i<=MAX` to `i < MAX`.  Your array is `MAX` = 512 elements long, the first element is `a[0]`, the second is `a[1]`, the 500th is `a[499]`.  There is no `a[512]`.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I am curious why did the operator less or equal did not work.

Comment: Because `i<=MAX` will cause the body of the loop to be executed for `i = MAX`, which will cause the code `*(p + MAX) = 128`, equivalently `*(p + 512) = 128`, equivalently `p[512] = 128`, to be run.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been struggling with the assignment for the past hour or so.